# How can I have a copy of same robot in Gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a robot, now I want to have a copy of the same robot in Gazebo simulation.
Please tell How can I achieve it? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258600/how-can-i-have-a-copy-of-same-robot-in-gazebo-simulation/) by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can spawn multiple instances of the same model via launch files. The [lots_of_robots.launch](https://github.com/nkoenig/pioneer3at_demo/blob/master/p3at_description/launch/lots_of_robots.launch) example launch file spawns 100 Pioneer 3 AT robots into Gazebo for instance ([screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/nkoenig/pioneer3at_demo/images/army_of_pioneers.png)) ;) It's a small demo I created at a workshop last year, and should give you an idea how you can do it also for fewer robots. Setting up the correct group namespaces and tf for onboard software can be a bit tricky though.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2